# How to add background for each text label in stacked bar in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, nvd3.js

I've tried different ways to give background of text label on each bar to make it more visible. But I'm unable to add background to each text label in my stacked bar also I've total of each bar, which I want to append on above each stacked bar as [Total : 250].

In the graph below you can see grey rectangle area, which I tried to make background of text but failed. I'm new to D3.js and really struggling to make it happen. Kindly help me out with this.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style>
    .textRect {
      fill: white;
      stroke: none;
    }
    
    text {
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body style="width: 98%; background-color: white">
  <div id="ashu" style="width: 700px; height:400px; padding-top: 50px;"></div>
  <script>
    var data = [{
      "health": "JAN",
      "val1": 1,
      "val2": 67,
      "val3": 13,
      "val4": 15
    }, {
      "health": "FEB",
      "val1": 60,
      "val2": 9,
      "val3": 20,
      "val4": 5
    }, {
      "health": "MAR",
      "val1": 40,
      "val2": 22,
      "val3": 21,
      "val4": 99
    }, {
      "health": "APR",
      "val1": 60,
      "val2": 1,
      "val3": 99,
      "val4": 90
    }, {
      "health": "MAY",
      "val1": 2,
      "val2": 27,
      "val3": 43,
      "val4": 82
    }, {
      "health": "JUN",
      "val1": 17,
      "val2": 52,
      "val3": 79,
      "val4": 9
    }, {
      "health": "JUL",
      "val1": 37,
      "val2": 24,
      "val3": 35,
      "val4": 51
    }, {
      "health": "AUG",
      "val1": 16,
      "val2": 17,
      "val3": 53,
      "val4": 38
    }, {
      "health": "SEP",
      "val1": 15,
      "val2": 32,
      "val3": 5,
      "val4": 31
    }];
    let xData = d3.keys(data[0]);
    const yData = xData.shift();
    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 0);

    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 400,
      height = 300,
      padding = 100;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
    var y_axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(6).innerTickSize(-width)
      .tickPadding(10);

    var svg = d3.select("#ashu").append("svg").attr("width",
      "100%").attr("height",
      "100%").append("g").attr(
      "transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var dataIntermediate = xData.map(function(c) {
      return data.map(function(d, yData) {
        return {
          x: d[Object.keys(d)[0]],
          y: d[c]
        };
      });
    });
    var chu = 0;
    var totals = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) {
        return d.health;
      })
      .rollup(function(d) {
        return d3.sum(d, function(g) {

          return g.val1 + g["val2"] + g.val3 + g.val4;
        });
      })
      .entries(data);

    var dataStackLayout = d3.layout.stack()(dataIntermediate);

    x.domain(dataStackLayout[0].map(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    }));
    var total = 0;
    var maximumY = d3.max(dataStackLayout[dataStackLayout.length - 1], function(d) {
      return (d.y + d.y0);
    });
    y.domain([0, maximumY]).nice();

    var layer1 = svg.selectAll(".stack1").data(dataStackLayout).enter()
      .append("g").attr("class", "stack1").style("fill",
        function(d, i) {
          return color(i);
        });

    layer1.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.x);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.y + d.y0);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0);
      })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand());

    var layer2 = svg.selectAll(".stack2").data(dataStackLayout).enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "stack2")
      .style("fill", "black");

    layer2.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "textRect")

      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return x(d.x) + (x.rangeBand()) / 2 - (this.getBBox().width / 2);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.y0 + (d.y / 2)) - (this.getBBox().height / 2);
      }).attr("height", function(d) {
        return d.y0 / 2 - (this.getBBox().width / 2);
      })
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return d.y0 / 2 - (this.getBBox().height / 2);
      })
      .style("opacity", "0.6")
      .style("fill", "grey");

    var textLabel = layer2.selectAll("text")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return x(d.x) + (x.rangeBand()) / 2;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.y0 + (d.y / 2));
      })
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("fill", "white");

    /*    var bbox =  textLabel.each(function() {
           return this.getBBox();// get bounding box of text field and store it in texts array
       });
     console.log(bbox);
     var paddingLeftRight = 18; // adjust the padding values depending on font and font size
        var paddingTopBottom = 5;
     
       var rectLabel =  layer2.selectAll("rect")
       .data(function(d) {
           return d;
         })
         .enter()
         .append("rect")
     .attr("class", "textRect")
        .attr("x", function(d) { d.x.x - d.x.width/2 - paddingLeftRight/2; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { d.y.y - d.y.height + paddingTopBottom/2; })
        .attr("width", function(d) { return d.y.width + paddingLeftRight; })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return d.y.height + paddingTopBottom; }).style("fill", "#ccc")
        .style("fill-opacity", ".3")
        .style("stroke", "#666")
        .style("stroke-width", "1.5px");
       
     */

    svg.append("g").attr("class", "axis").attr("transform",
      "translate(0," + height + ")").call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").attr("transform", "translate(0,0)").call(y_axis);

    var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain().slice())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(0," + Math.abs((i - 8) * 20) + ")";
      });

    legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width + 10)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

    legend.append("text")
      .attr("class", "legendText")
      .attr("x", width + 32)
      .attr("y", 10)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "start")
      .text(function(d, i) {
        return xData[i];
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you considered just using `text-shadow` css to make the text more visible? Or does it have to be rectangles?

Comment: @Robert : text-shadow not working, want to add some background colour for label text which make it more visible. I'm not specific to rectangle shape but I'm new so don't know how to make it happen so trying different ways.

Comment: Doesn't this work for you? https://plnkr.co/edit/OO1xuVpOuP1dmnrr9KUm?p=preview What browser are you using?

Comment: @robert this looks good. But can we expand smaller bars wrt to yaxis. So that bars will be always hold labels inside it?

Comment: Sorry to say but I'm using IE, can't help it official app.

Comment: Not sure how that would work, I think what you'd really need is a on-hover tooltip. Like [this](https://bl.ocks.org/lemonode/ee3d70f42cfbe03643061383c9db19df) , it guarantees that you'll always see the values no matter how small.

Comment: @Robert on hover tooltip will be not printer friendly.